# pass attrs to BoundField.as_widget() django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to pass HTML attributes with `BoundField.as_widget()` by passing them to `attrs` in the method. [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.as_widget) says

> BoundField.as_widget(widget=None, attrs=None, only_initial=False)¶
>
> Renders the field by rendering the passed widget, adding any HTML attributes passed as attrs. If no widget is specified, then the field’s default widget will be used.

So I tried passing attributes like this: `BoundField.as_widget(attrs={'class': 'container'})`, which didn't work.

forms.py

```
class HiddenForm(forms.Form):
    testfield = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.HiddenInput())

class BlahForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blah
```

views.py. Model `Blah` is a One-To-OneField relationship to Model `A`.

```
def myview(request, arg):
    a = get_object_or_404(A, somefieldname=arg)
    initial = {'blah': a}
    form = BlahForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial) # ModelForm from Model Blah
    value = a.pk 

    hidden_input = HiddenForm(request.POST or None)
    hidden_input['testfield'].as_widget(attrs={'value': value }) # This is the reason I want to pass attrs with as_widget. I want to pass value to the hidden input form, so that the hidden form can handle submitting disabled form value, which I did on purpose to keep user from changing the value.

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('somewhere', someparameter=arg)
    context = {
            'form': form,
            'value': value,
            'hidden_input': hidden_input
            }
    return render(request, 'someapp/sometemplate.html', context)
```

sometemplate.html

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  {# disabled input data not submitted, so submit it with hidden data #}
  <input type="hidden" name="blah" value="{{ value }}"> <!-- hard coded part, which I try to avoid -->
  {{ hidden_input }} <!-- What I want -->
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">저장</button>
</form>
```

and what I see developer console page below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="blah" value="2632"> <!-- hard coded -->
<input type="hidden" name="blah" id="id_blah"> <!-- rendered with {{ hidden_input }}-->
```

As far as I understood, Django discourages putting the design in the template directly, but to put the business model in views and other `.py` files, so I want my template to look more elegant.

Could someone tell me what I missed, or did it wrongly?

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass those attributes when you define a widget on a field in `HiddenForm`:

```py
class HiddenForm(forms.Form):
    testfield = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'value': value }))
```

If you want to pass `attrs` dynamically in your view then do it this way:

```py
hidden_input['testfield'].field.widget.attrs.update({'value': 'value'})
```

Or:

```py
hidden_input['testfield'].field.widget.attrs = {'value': 'value'}
```

Or you can change the widget completely:

```py
hidden_input['testfield'].field.widget = forms.HiddenInput({'value': value })
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know I can put `attrs` when defining form in `forms.py`. I want to know if there is any way to do the similar thing in views.py, since the `value` is defined in views.

Comment: Updated my answer